# Set owner information

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, xiaomi

I just installed unofficial version of cyanogenmod on my Redmi 1s but when i pull down the quick settings and click on users I cannot find my name in place of owner.On going to more settings and clicking on the owner it says no contact found. How do i set the owner information? I already have set the owner information under security option in settings.

Comment: Go to People or Contact app and you will find a  contact named **Me**.  Edit it

Answer (score 2):

Go to of your app drawer. Then search for the app **Contacts**. Open it. To edit the owner information you should go to the **Me** contact. It is at the very top.(not by the "m") there you can set all the information for the owner. When you are finished, tap save.

In **Settings** go to **Lock Screen**, then you will see an option **Owner Info** like in the screenshot below:

[image]

That is an option where you can type some text and it will be displayed on your **Lock Screen** like this:

[image]

Hope my answer helps. For any question just leave a comment below instead of down voting.